# Whats wrong in this lightning code it shows error : "Can not read property of value undeifined"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I am new to lightning, I will be really thankful if someone can help me for this code.

Purpose : want to show employee list and a search bar above it.

Error : on writing anything in the search bar it shows

> error "Can not read property of value undefined".

Code :

component :

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="EditAllocationPage1Controller">
     <link href='/resource/bootstrap/' rel="stylesheet"/>
    <aura:attribute name="plan" type="Plan__c[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="emp" type="Employee__c[]" />
     <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
     <aura:attribute name="searchKey" type="String"/>
   <aura:handler event="c:SearchKeyChange" action="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>
    <aura:registerevent name="searchKeyChange" type="c:SearchKeyChange"/>
    <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Interactive Seating Arrangement</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <label>Action : </label>
                <select id='NextComponent' tabindex="-1" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="CreateLayout">Create Layout</option>
  <option value="ManageLayou">Manage Layout</option>
  <option value="ManagePlans">Manage Plans</option>
  <option value="ViewOrganisation">View Organisation</option>
</select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <h5 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Plan Management</h5>
        <div class="slds-grid">

<div>

                <div class="slds-col">
                    <div>
                        <br/>
                        <lightning:select label="Select the floor plan" name="a_opt" aura:id="a_opt" tabindex="-1" class="selectpicker" onchange="{!c.catchPlanId}">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.plan}" var="plan">
                                <option class="slds-dropdown__item" tabindex="-1" value="{!plan.Name}" >{!plan.Name}</option>

                            </aura:iteration>
                        </lightning:select>
                        <br/>
                        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Show" onclick="{!c.associatedPlan }" />
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--small">
            <legend id="employee details" class="slds-text-heading--medium">
                Employees
            </legend>
                <input type="text" class="slds-input" onkeyup="{!c.searchKeyChange}"
            placeholder="Search" value="{!v.searchKey}"/>
                <br/>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.emp}" var="emp">
                <ul>
                    <li draggable="true" class="slds-page-header" tabindex="-1" value="{!emp.Id}">{!emp.Name}</li>
                 </ul>

            </aura:iteration>
         </fieldset>
    </div>
         <div class="slds-col">check
         <div class="slds-col-md-12" aura:id="holder" id="holder">dfhgdfhj
         </div>
        <div class="row"/>dfgdfhg
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

controller :

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.getAllPlans");
        action.setCallback(this, function(result){
        var plan = result.getReturnValue();
        console.log(plan);
        component.set("v.plan", plan);
        window.setTimeout(
                $A.getCallback( function() {

                    // Now set our preferred value
                    component.find("a_opt").set("v.value", plan[0].Id);


                }));
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        var action = component.get("c.getAllEmployees");
        action.setCallback(this, function(result){
            var emp = result.getReturnValue();
            console.log(emp);
            component.set("v.emp", emp);
            // Let DOM state catch up.

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },
    catchPlanId: function(component, event, helper) {
        var target = event.getSource(); 
          var selectCmp = component.find("a_opt").get("v.value");
        console.log(selectCmp);
    },
     searchKeyChange: function(component, event) {
    var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:SearchKeyChange");
    myEvent.setParams({"searchKey": event.target.value});
    myEvent.fire();
    var searchKey = event.getParam("searchKey");
    var action = component.get("c.findByName");
    action.setParams({
      "searchKey": searchKey
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        component.set("v.emp", a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}

}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some points you must fix here...

First of all

Your problem is based in the handling of c:SearchKeyChange event.
You use the same function to handle a DOM Event and a Framework Event, NEVER DO THIS because "event" argument never contains the same information.

OK...
The first handler that is invoked is the DOM Event handler where "event" argument contains the "native" DOM Event object, in this handler you fire a Framework event with the value of "target" property and it is captured by the same function. In this next handling context "event" exist, but "target" doesn't because the source of the event is a Framework event and not a DOM event.

You can resolve this following the next advices.

-Adding an event handler on "keyup" event is a terrible bad practice for the impact in the performance of the framework and network, every time you release a key, you are sending a request to the server to query some data this is an expensive workload for the server. Try to do it on "blur" event.

-If you are adding a event handler to the input to retrieve the data entered, is not necessary to create a Lightning event, pass the data of the input as parameter and then handle it again. They are redundant operations.

-Dont rely on "target" property of DOM Event object, "currentTarget" is a better option for this use case, Watch this -> [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

-Always you are handling a DOM Event, be sure the target you are watching for exist.

```
eventHandler:function(component,event,helper){
    //var declarations
    if(event.currentTarget){
        //your code
    }
}
```

I'm sure you are tired of reading tech literature like this, so here it is your code

```
searchKeyChange: function(component, event) {
    var searchKey;
    var action = component.get("c.findByName");
    if (event.currentTarget) {
        searchKey = event.currentTarget.value;
        if (action) {
            action.setParams({
                "searchKey": searchKey
            });
            action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                component.set("v.emp", a.getReturnValue());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!